# LinkedServer Openquery is throwing this error : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I am running below query in SQL Server 2012 against a linked server and i am getting below error.
Am I using an incorrect keyword/function or missing any syntex. 
The query is running fine when I am running without openquery

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The query is below :

```
select * from openquery(LinkedServerName,
'select t.TRANSACTION,t.PARTNER,t.DATE

from

(select st.TRANSACTION,st.PARTNER,st.DATE
,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by st.TRANSACTION order by st.DATE desc)
from tbltransactions st) t where t.RowNum = 1')
```

Comment: `RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() ...` is not the way you assign an alias in Oracle (or standard SQL)

Comment: Thanks for picking this @a_horse_with_no_name. Could you please help me correct this?

Comment: Well obviously the way you always specify a column alias in standard SQL: `row_number() over (...) as rownum`

Comment: Maybe I am doing something silly but I am receiving a different error after updating this alias.

ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function

Comment: Oh Thanks let me update this one..

Comment: The updated alias is runing fine without openquery but it is throwing same error  ORA-00923 in openquery : 
row_number() over (partition by st.TRANSACTION order by st.DATE desc) as RowNum

Comment: Hey It just did the trick. I used all the functions in upper case and it worked in openquery. Great help!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
select * from openquery(LinkedServerName,
'select t.TRANSACTION,t.PARTNER,t.DATE

from

(select st.TRANSACTION,st.PARTNER,st.DATE
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by st.TRANSACTION order by st.DATE desc) as RowNum
from tbltransactions st) t where t.RowNum = 1')
```